# My sums are way too huge, is it not possible to do them all at once?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with colleague info, including their IDs, and a separate table with transaction data (such as revenue).

In the transaction table, there are three fields (code1, code2, code3), they could be blank, or have colleague IDs, etc. I have no control over these tables.

I am trying to accumulate some sums by colleague, so right now I have things like this:

```
SELECT Colleagues.Name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Trans1.Code1 IS NOT NULL AND Trans1.RevMth <= 3 THEN Trans1.Rev END) as Sum1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Trans2.Code2 IS NOT NULL AND Trans2.RevMth <= 3 THEN Trans2.Rev END) as Sum2, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Trans3.Code3 IS NOT NULL AND Trans3.RevMth <= 3 THEN Trans3.Rev END) as Sum3

FROM 
Colleagues LEFT OUTER JOIN
Trans AS Trans1 ON Colleagues.ID = Trans1.code1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
Trans AS Trans2 ON Colleagues.ID = Trans2.code2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
Trans AS Trans3 ON Colleagues.ID = Trans3.code3 

GROUP BY Colleagues.Name
```

Basically summing up values wherever their codes are found in the table for each code, which I've already done using the SUMIFS function on the same data in Excel so I have something to compare to, and normally I could write three separate queries, one for each sum, and then join those in later, but I am trying to do it all in one query.

However the sums that SQL are returning are huge, is there an obvious reason why?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Maybe `SUM(IIF((Trans1.Code1 IS NOT NULL AND Trans1.RevMth <=3), Trans1.Rev, 0)) as Sum1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you really want a Cartesian product of the transactions.  Instead, I think you just want to pick colleagues out of three columns and add up the revenue for which column they are in.

This is easy to do with `APPLY` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.Name, SUM(v.rev1), SUM(v.rev2), SUM(v.rev3)
FROM Trans t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (t.code1, t.rev, 0, 0), (t.code2, 0, t.rev, 0), (t.code3, 0, 0, t.rev)
     ) v(code, rev1, rev2, rev3) JOIN
     Colleagues c
     ON c.id = v.code
WHERE t.RevMth <= 3
GROUP BY c.Name
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, thank you - is there a good resource or explanation for how CROSS APPLY is working here?

Comment: @user525966 . . . I recommend that you start with the documentation on `cross apply`.  Technically, it is implementing a *lateral join*.